# Pandas query not working with square brackets in column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have to evaluate a lot of csv files. The columns of the files are always in a different order because some columns were removed and some new were added. Some columns are in every file and have the same name, therefore I want to switch from numpy to pandas because it's possible to access the data by the column name.
I want to calculate the average of a column dependent on the values in another column.

First I want to filter the values:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"Y Position [0] [mm]": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "Y Position [1] [mm]": [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

dq = df.query("`Y Position [0] [mm]` > 2")
print(dq)
```

But I get this error:

```
File "<unknown>", line 1
    Y_Position_[_0_]_[_mm_]_BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING >2
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I remove the square brackets it works fine:

```
   Y Position 0  Y Position [1] [mm]
2             3                    8
3             4                    9
4             5                    0
```

I checked the documentation but I could not find a reason why it should not work.

Comment: It seems like the .query function is not the best suited for your problem [see this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508). It is quite limiting in terms of your column names. You would be better off using the df[df["Y Position [0] [mm]"] > 2] notation to achive the same effect.

Comment: The query function is a good tool because it's efficiency. Also these column names limit you in other operations too. Why not to rename your columns? If you really need them you can return to the old names later.